# using flash and av mode

Tags: canon, flash, canon-1000d

I shoot with canon 1000d and in av mode. I prefer not to use flash but some times i use it (built in) to fill-in dark in day light.

Flash make my photo too much over exposed. Any suggestion for using flash in day light and camera settings will be a great help

Comment: Could you post an example or a link to an example of one of the shots you are not happy with?

Comment: Hi Michael, i delete those photos, they were ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using ETTL, and are not happy with your camera's choices regarding flash power, just set the FEC (flash exposure compensation). You can bias the camera to to use less power, a very nice discussion of this can be found [here](http://neilvn.com/tangents/flash-photography-techniques/flash-exposure-compensation/).

The important takeaway is that your camera cannot know what you are thinking and there is no difference (to your camera) between using flash as the primary exposure and a simple fill - creative choices are in your control and that is why FEC exists.

Answer (score 0):

Are you shooting with ISO set to automatic?  You can recover some control by setting ISO to 100, 200 or 400.  This will give the camera just shutter speed and flash power to control exposure.

Is it just the foreground that is overexposed?  If so, you can recompose to have a different foreground.  If you like those foreground elements, then you may have to go to manual to control both aperature and shutter speed.

Patrick Hurley's answer is a very good approach and goes straight to the fix if you are comfortable using the 1000D's menus.  (I would comment his answer if I had the rep).

Comment: Hi Ubante, I normally control ISO. Its the entire photo which turns white, overexposing almost everything.